# javascript async/await output order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

```js
        if (element[0] === '@notify_1_2') {
          // @ts-ignore
          async function checkStorage() {
            const json = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@alarm')
            const response = JSON.parse(json!)

            let dayDifference: any
            if (json !== null) {
              dayDifference = daysDiff(response, Date.now())
            }

            if (dayDifference > 30 || dayDifference == null) {
              return { id: 1, priority: 1 }
            }
          }

          checkStorage().then((res) => {
                console.log('in function on top of push', arrayTracker)
                arrayTracker.push(res)
                console.log('in function bottom of push', arrayTracker)
              })
        } else {
          arrayTracker.push({ id: 0, priority: 0 })
        }
      }
    })

    console.log('array tracker:', arrayTracker)
```

Output:

```js
array tracker outside function: []
in function on top of push []
in function bottom of push [{…}]
```

I want it so that the `array tracker outside function: []` console log waits till all the async/await stuff are done with their checks.

Right now I push a value to array but it always seems empty but in the console log bottom of push it seems like the value gets passed - seems like some async/await order I couldn't get right

Output wanted:

```js
in function on top of push []
in function bottom of push [{…}]
array tracker outside function: [{…}]. <------ with value and not empty
```

**EDIT**

```js
  response.forEach(async (element: any) => {
    const formatJson = JSON.parse(element[1])

    if (formatJson !== null) {
      const dayDifference = daysDiff(formatJson.closedTimeStamp, Date.now())

      if (dayDifference > 7) {
        arrayTracker.push(formatJson)
      }
    } else {
      if (element[0] === '@notify_1_2') {
        // @ts-ignore
        async function checkStorage() {
          const json = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@alarm')
          const response = JSON.parse(json!)

          let dayDifference: any
          if (json !== null) {
            dayDifference = daysDiff(response, Date.now())
          }

          if (dayDifference > 7 || dayDifference == null) {
            return { id: 1, priority: 1 }
          }
        }

        arrayTracker.push(await checkStorage())
        console.log('array tracker below push:', arrayTracker)
      } else {
        arrayTracker.push({ id: 0, priority: 0 })
      }
    }
  })

  console.log('array tracker outside function:', arrayTracker)
```

Output:

```js
array tracker outside function: []
array tracker below push: [{…}]
```

Output wanted:

```js
array tracker below push: [{…}]
array tracker outside function: [{…}]
```

Comment: What's the context of this code? Is it inside another function? If so, make that one `async` and do `arrayTracker.push(await checkStorage())` instead.

Comment: Or use `Promise.all` if you don't want to run each async function sequentially but want to wait for all of them to finish.

Comment: Where are you awaiting?  It seems like the function you are in is not async or you are not awaiting it. Specifically because you are doing `checkStorage().then` instead of `await checkStorage()`, even in an async function it will not wait before moving on.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat I have edited the code to show you with the modifications - The output is the same

Comment: @FelixKling Edited the code base with your suggestion - its giving me the same output

Comment: Because you still have the same problem. `response.forEach` won't wait until the async functions "are done". You want `Promise.all(response.map(...)).then(() => console.log(...))` or `await Promise.all(response.map(...)); console.log(...);`. And depending on how `arrayTracker` is used there might also be a cleaner way to create that array than to push to it. Anyways, this might help with how to think about think about callbacks that mutate "outside" values: https://felix-kling.de/blog/2019/javascript-callbacks-misconceptions.html

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop

Comment: @FelixKling - really helpful and thanks for article

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not awaiting your call to `checkStorage()`:

```js
checkStorage().then((res) => {
      console.log('in function on top of push', arrayTracker)
      arrayTracker.push(res)
      console.log('in function bottom of push', arrayTracker)
    })
```

When you call `checkStorage()`, it begins executing.  Then the first statement it hits is this:

```js
const json = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@alarm')
```

Now this is an async call that might take a while.  Now your code resumes below your `checkStorage()` call and your function can complete.  Later when `checkStorage()` completes, the code inside your `then()` will execute.

Instead you need to use `await checkStorage()`.  This means the function it is in needs to be async as well, and you need to await it.

```js
const res = await checkStorage();
console.log('in function on top of push', arrayTracker)
arrayTracker.push(res)
console.log('in function bottom of push', arrayTracker)
```